# Use github actions to add deploy key to repo?

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to add a deploy key with GitHub actions. I have already generates key with ssh-keygen and tried to add it manually which works. But I would like to add my generated key with GitHub actions as well.

In other words I want to do this "GitHub -> repo -> settings -> deploy keys -> add deploy key (the generated key during workflow)" but I want to do it with GitHub actions if it's possible.

This is the workflow that i have created so far:

```
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.repository.name != 'testar-deploy-key'
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create deploy key
        run: |
          # Deploy key
          ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "mail@mail.com"  -o -f id_rsa
          #Here i want in someway to add my generated key to the current github repository.
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Generate SSH"
      # Push changes
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          branch: main
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to add the key as a secret during the workflow run that generated it, then use it, and removing the secret at the end of the workflow?

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Does adding the key as a secret making it possible to add it as a deploy key? If that's the case it would definitely be a solution for it.

Comment: Depending on how you use the deploy key, it might be possible yes. It would be easier to tell you if you add an example of your workflow in the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I have now added the code I have created so far. The repository i'm working with is a template repository on github for iot-devices. When i'm creating a new repository using "use this template" I want to have a new deploy key generated and added to the newly created repository on github. The purpose of this is to track configuration files on each of the iot-devices i have and also make it very simple to set up a new iot-device.

Comment: This workflow would run only once for each repository then, correct? Maybe you could use the step by step suggested here: https://tabris.com/using-deploy-keys-on-github-actions/, adding a step to add the encrypted_key variable to the repo secrets, to use it later on other workflows using the key.